# How to get a kernel thread ID?

Tags: linux-kernel

When we create a kernel thread using `kthread_run()`, how we can get the tid of the thread, is there something like `pthread_self()` or `gettid()` in kernel space?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In kernel-space, you don't need to ask something about thread like in userspace you do by calling `gettid()` -- you already have access to `task_struct` of your task:

```
struct task_struct* tsk = kthread_run(...);
pid_t tid = tsk->pid; // Thread id of newly created task (if it was successful)
```

Comment: (After a while) i figured it out that if there are several thread `pid_t tid = current->pid` will do the job for the running thread.